# convert urls to domains using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a `$urls` array, that contain urls of some pictures or anything else:

```
$urls = array("http://shop.google.com/pic/android2014-1.jpg",
"http://shop.about.com/pic/buy2.gif",
"http://shop.ebay.com/pic/android2014-2.jpg",
"http://shop.somesite.com/pic/android2014-3.jpg",
"http://shop.wordpress.com/pic/android2014-6.jpg",
"http://shop.test.com/pic/android2014-4.jpg");
```

I need to my output to be something like this:

```
$domains = array("shop.google.com",
"shop.about.com",
"shop.ebay.com",
"shop.somesite.com",
"shop.wordpress.com",
"shop.test.com");
```

I found a solution like [this example](http://webgarb.com/tutorials/get-domain-from-url-path-php/). It works well, but I want to use regular expression in my `foreach` loop. I think I should use `preg_math` and I read the php.net documentation, but I don't know how can I do this with `regular expression`

Comment: Why preg_match? There are other solutions like http://in3.php.net/parse_url

Comment: @Ramesh `parse_url` is good idea but i want to know how can i do something like this with regular expression

Comment: @Prakash i think my regular expression pattern is wrong and i don't insert it to this post , i am newbie in php and regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$domains=array();
foreach($urls as $url){
    $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    array_push($domains,$domain);
}
```

You can simply `print_r($domains);` to print the domain names.

---

**Using Regular expression**

```
preg_match("/^(http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i", $url, $matches);
$domain = $matches[2];
```

Comment: thankyou , it works nice , if possible i will be thankful if you write an example to do this with regular expression

Comment: You're done. Please mark the answer as correct if this really helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Functional style:

```
$domains = array_map(function($url) { return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); }, $urls); 
var_dump($domains);
```

See working example [here](http://ideone.com/e5Ia6j).

Comment: I don't know why answers suggest regex and pushing and popping into the array, I was going to suggest this function but found that you already did, this is much simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/(?<=http:\/\/)(.*?)(?=\/)/sm", $input_line, $output_array);
```

---

**Explanation**

The first part is using positive lookbehind to match anything after the "http://" (google [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)" for more information).

```
(?<=http:\/\/)(.*?)
```

The Last part is using positive lookahead to match anything before the /(folder)/(filename).gif:

```
(?=\/)
```

**Result:** http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3TZ

---

**To also match https (or other protocols)**

```
preg_match("/(?<=\w:\/\/)(.*?)(?=\/)/sm", $input_line, $output_array);
```

**Result:** http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3U0

Comment: Never use regexp if you could avoid it

Comment: @vooD The OP specifically asked for regular expression... "I think I should use preg_math and I read the php.net documentation, but I don't know how can I do this with regular expression".

Comment: @vooD can you explain me why we shouldn't use regexp ?
i am newbie